# struck at sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) constraint failed 'INSERT INTO users

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am using sqlite database and I declared the models as in this gist

https://gist.github.com/mmahesh/7245561

I have added a model instance with transaction manager as

```
with transaction.manager:
    model = Users(username='example',name='Example', email_primary='m@m.com', _password='example')
    DBSession.add(model)
```

Whenever I execute initialize_sample_db development.ini, this error shows up

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) constraint failed 'INSERT INTO users (name, username, email_primary, email_secondary, _password, bio) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' ('Example', 'example', 'm@m.com', None, 'example', None )
```

Additional Information:
when i use sqlite3 command tool and after '.d' command i get

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
COMMIT;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In table `users` you have defined column `id` as primary key.
However, in your `INSERT` statement you do not provide `id`.

That would be totally fine if `id` was auto-increment column - but it is not.

Solution is to add [`sqlite_autoincrement=True`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html) into your `users` table definition.

Also, your `users` table definitions seems to be too strict - you require most fields to be non-nullable. It depends on your task, but sometimes being too strict can be bad idea - it will also cause constraint violation if you forgot (or simply don't want) to fill one of those fields.

Comment: personally i like to start with strong constraints and remove them when really necessary;